# Android studio: hide history of changes bar at the right of the editor

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Is it possible to remove the right bar, which displays history of changes?

I want to clean my workspace, but I can't find any option to remove this:

[image: Screenshot of the Android Studio 1.2 Beta 3, demonstrating the bar I want to hide]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to remove this bar. It shares space with the vertical scrollbar, which is fairly essential for editor navigation.